# unable to connect ubuntu phone to thunar

Tags: ubuntu-touch, thunar

the first time I connect my Aquaris E 5 HD ubuntu edition phone

to Thunar in Xubuntu, my phone appears as

mtp://[usb:001,008]/

so I dont know how to connect the bq phone to the thinkpad  ?